# LINQ to Entities 2010 Tutorial available?

Tags: linq-to-entities

I understand that LINQ to SQL is being deprecated and that LINQ to Entities is what one should move to.  I also understand that LINQ to Entities has been greatly improved in VS 2010.  Is there a good tutorial for LINQ to Entities specifically using VB .NET 2010 and also covering the 2010 improvements?  I have searched high and low on the internet could find neither book nor tutorial.

Thanks.

Comment: >>LINQ to SQL is being deprecated<<     what makes you think that?

Comment: MS said so.  They don't have the resources to do both, so they're electing to do LINQ to Entities, which will go beyond SQL Server.  They have also made it more seamless in VS 2010, so the difficulties it had in VS2008 are gone.  This is what I'm seeing on the Internet.  Many developers are disappointed though.

Answer (score 1):

First, LINQ to SQL is not dead. There was a lot of [discussions](http://jonkruger.com/blog/2009/06/06/linq-to-sql-is-not-dead/), and it is still present in .NET 4.0.
For example, we provide a [LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/) product that is an implementation of LINQ to SQL for several DBMS (namely, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite) with some [enhancements](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/linq-to-sql-extensions.html).
As for Entity Framework learning resources, take a look at a [book by Julie Lerman](http://learnentityframework.com/learnentityframework/), for example.
Some tutorials and articles:

- [Getting Started MSDN Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx)
- [Model First in Entity Framework 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff830362)
- [Code First in Entity Framework 4.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  Went through the Quick Start of the Getting Started.  The Julie Lerman book is a C# book; I'm looking for a VB book.  But thanks for that.  I may have to make it work with a C# - VB coded translator.